# send an auto email with account details

Tags: twilio-php

I have a database and there some tables.
There are some users in the table users
I am trying to create a form which the user will be able to get his/her password to his/her email.
I would like to send an automatic email with both username and password (which are fields in the table named 'users')

Comment: Both scripts do not connect to the database. I guess another file which is included handles the database connection. I have to say, sending a user a username and password is not very secure. Instead sending a user an hashed link on which they can create a new password is much more secure.

Comment: to have the right foundation, please kindly take php mysql tutorial. Also do not learn programming by developing a login system. You need to go back to the roots, such as for loops, arrays, object oriented, procedural, lists, variable scopes etc

Comment: @Leroy for this purpose I don't need secure

Comment: You should NEVER print a password on a web page. It is easy for people to gain access to a persons account

Comment: @EdHeal that was just to check , I will remove it

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a database, [please read this page](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp). You need to connect to a database before you can perform any action with SQL in your file. Also consider security when sending account details by mail, especially unencrypted passwords. Even if you're practising it's a good exercise to make a secure system.

Comment: Hi , I tried but it still doesnt work.. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50199781/php-html-and-mysql-send-auto-email

Answer (score 0):

```
//you can connect to you database with the following code
mysql_connect(HOST, USR, PSD);
mysql_select_db(DB);
/*where HOST = Database host server eg localhost
      USR = Database username
      PSD = Databse password
      DB = The name of the database that contain the table
*/
```

place the code after

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

PS
using mysql is has been deprecated and remove as of php 7. Try to use PDO or [MYSQLI](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Comment: it appears a blank page

Comment: Sorry, what appears blank page

Comment: see my new post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50199781/php-html-and-mysql-send-auto-email